# char - This local variable may not have been initialised

Tags: java, char, local-variables

I'm trying to make a basic calculator to learn Java and it keeps saying 'This local variable may not have been initialised' in my switch statement. Here is a segment of the code

```
char operator;

    System.out.println("Enter First number");
    firstNumber = scan.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Enter Second Number");
    secondNumber = scan.nextDouble();

    switch(operator) { 
     case '+':
        answer = firstNumber + secondNumber;
        System.out.println("Result = "+ answer);
        break;
```

(after this it carries on with the switch statement)

When I try to compile my program it tells me that in switch(operator) the operator hasn't been initialised and says 'This local variable may not have been initialised' with a red line under 'operator'.

It told me that I should write:

```
char operator = 0;
```

That didn't work so I tried

```
 char operator = null;
```

And that too didn't work
It automatically runs to

```
default:
       System.out.println("Syntax Error");
```

which is my default if the case isn't done properly. It runs to this because I have already defined what the Operator should be.

What do I do to solve this problem?

PS sorry if this is a messy post(it's my first on StackOverflow), if you need anymore information just ask

Comment: What is the sample input and output? How are you giving value to operator?

Comment: You never assign anything to `operator`, but you're expecting the program to do something useful with it?

Comment: `0` isn't a character it's an integer so yes `char operator = 0` would fail. You could initialize it to `char operator = '0';` but really why would you if you are for some reason expecting it to match a `+` in the switch statement? Where do you expect the value for the operator variable to come from?

Comment: You are assigning an int to a char. Instead, assign an arbitrary character, like '0', ' ', etc. Also, no operator is assigned to operator, so the program won't do anything meaningful with it. Does your method take any operands? Edit: you should research your question before posting it to Stack Overflow if you don't want it to be downvoted into oblivion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use following code in this case.char operator has to be initialized before use

```
System.out.println("choose operator");
operator c = scan.next().charAt(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your switch statement you have case only for `+`, so initializing operator to 0 or null will match nothing but `default`  case. Better initialize it with `+`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do only opperation "+" for instace, so initialize operator with:
`operator = '+';`
But, if yout want the choose some operation to do the calc so initialize operator with null, ask for operation on the console:

```
System.out.println("choose operator");
operator = scan.next().charAt(0);
```

Now you can use operator on switch case without problem. 
You also send a message on default case if the chat typed its not in cases statements.